# onRemove event not firing

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a some `bootstrap-tagsinput` code:

```
<div x-show.transition.in="step === 1">
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <strong>Job Area:</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- <input name="job_area" placeholder="Select a job area or type to insert another." class="form-control" \> -->
        <select multiple data-role="tagsinput" name="job_area" id="job_area" placeholder="Select a job area or type to insert another."></select>
        <div class="row mt-2">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2" type="button" onclick="$('#job_area').tagsinput('add', 'Leadership'); $(this).hide();">Leadership</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2">Governance, Risk Management and  Compliance</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2">Offensive</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2">Defensive</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2">Security Engineering</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2">Architecture</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        $("input[name='job_area']").on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
        console.log('item added : '+event.item);
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to console log the item when a tag is removed however it is not firing. Have also tried different selectors to get the correct input. Nothing fires.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi your `job_area` is `select` tag not input change that and try again

Comment: Please share more details. In the given code, there is no active element that matches `input[name='job_area']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 issues I was having.
First, I wasn't using the right selector. I needed to use `select[name='job_area']` instead of `input`/

Secondly, my event listener was not in a `document.ready` call back.
Fixed it by wrapping docready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='job_area']").on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
        console.log('item removed : '+event.item);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" name="job_area" placeholder="Select a job area or type to insert another." data-role="tagsinput" >

  $("input[name='job_area']").on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
        console.log('item removed : '+event.item);
    });
```

You are selecting wrong element `job_area` is should be input type

Comment: Please share more details - are you sure that `itemRemoved` makes sense on a text field?

Comment: I just give example that he is using `input[name='job_area']` so type should be input . While itemRemoved work with both `select` and `input`. For more details check ::https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/